# Joomla mail send() senfing HTML Markup without rendering

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to send Emails from Joomla 2.5

```
 $subject = "Test Subject";
    $mail = JFactory::getMailer();
    $mail->addRecipient($contact->email_to);
    $mail->addReplyTo(array($email, $name));
    $mail->setSender(array($mailfrom, $fromname));
    $mail->setSubject($sitename . ': ' . $subject);
    $mail->setBody($body);
    echo $body;
    $sent = $mail->Send();
```

Variable `$body` outputs the rendered HTML but when receiving Email I get un-rendered Email.

Comment: add this under setbody `$mail->IsHTML(true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isHTML` as you can probably gather means theemail will be be sent in HTML mode. You should also set the encoding type to `base64` which will avoid unwanted characters, as shown below:

```
$mailer->isHTML(true);
$mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
```

So add the above code, right before `$mail->setBody($body);`.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Umair - In future, please ask your questions for Joomla on the dedicated [Joomla StackExchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) site ;)